# Ng-Bootstrap nav (tab) not showing content of tabs whatsoever

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-bootstrap

I created a stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ghhkp6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

I'm doing something wrong, but I don't understand what. I'm basically using the example on the website.

Any help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `<div [ngbNavOutlet]="nav"></div>` this `html` at the end of your `ul` element.
I tested it on stackblitz and it's working now. Updated stackbltiz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-knqfd2?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: ah, I do have it installed in my local project, seems like the stackblitz doesn't match perfectly my project. I have no errors in console, but the tabs don't show any content. I'm trying to mimic my project better in stackblitz

Comment: oh god. I kept assuming that part was to print the active index like in some examples, of course it's not. thanks a lot, I kept trying stuff and different examples and kept cutting that part out without thinking twice. I can't believe the ammount of time I wasted on this. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

The Dependency bootstrap is missing. Install ng-bootstrap with the following command, this automatically installs the bootstrap dependency as well:

```
ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

Comment: in my local installation I already had it:

    "Skipping installation: Package already installed"

Maybe I couldn't do it for the stackblitz, but the behavior was exactly the same. I did more testing and other components like the datepicker are working. I added datepicker to the stackblitz and it's doing the exact seame thing, datepicker seems to work but I can't make the tab content show up.